# Inverses of probability generating functions: positivity of derivatives

Tags: pr.probability, real-analysis, generating-functions, power-series

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of probability generating functions of random variables taking positive integer values, considered as functions on $[0,1]$.

So $G\in\mathcal{G}$ can be written $G(x)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty p_k x^k$ where $p_1, p_2, p_3, \dots$ are non-negative and sum to 1. Such a $G$ is a bijection from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$ whose derivatives exist and are non-negative everywhere on $[0,1)$.

> Suppose $G\in\mathcal{G}$, and define $H(x)=1-G^{-1}(1-x)$. Is it necessarily the case that $H\in\mathcal{G}$?

(The motivation is closely related to that described in the question [Involutions on $[0,1]$ given by power series (related to probability generating functions)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/215491/), which concerned the case where $H\equiv G$.)

EDIT: Thanks to Brendan McKay, who gives in the comments below the example $G(x)=\sum_{k\geq 2} \frac{x^k}{k(k-1)}$, for which one can show that $H''(0)$ diverges at $0$. I wonder if there are any natural general conditions on $G$ under which it does hold that $H$ must also be a probability generating function.

Comment: Consider the Cauchy-like distribution $G(x) = \sum_{i\ge 1} 6\pi^{-2}i^{-2}x^i$.  All its derivatives diverge as $x\to 1$, which I think means that all the derivatives of $1-G^{-1}(1-x)$ at $x=0$ are 0, which means it isn't a pgf.  In fact I question your characterisation of pgfs: I think they have to have a radius of convergence at least 1, which means they equal their Taylor series in $[0,1]$.

Comment: I don't think the derivatives diverging at 1 is a problem. (This just means that the mean is infinite, right?) I'm not sure about your particular example, but there are some that seem to work fine. For example, $G(x)=1-(1-x)^{1/2}$, which is a pdf with all derivatives diverging at 1, and which gives $H(x)=x^2$ which is a very well-behaved pdf. Or even $G(x)=[1-(1-x)^{1/2}]^2$, which gives $H\equiv G$.

Comment: I'm not completely sure about the characterisation (I intended it to say that all derivatives exist and are non-negative everywhere on $[0,1)$ ) so I've replaced it by something weaker....

Comment: I might not have identified the problem precisely, but I still think it is a problem. In the example I gave, I think that $H$ has no Taylor series at the origin.  But every pgf has a radius of convergence at least 1 since the coefficients are bounded by 1.  If $H$ is a pgf, you should be able to identify the probabilities it corresponds to.

Comment: Precisely (contrary to what I wrote before), I think $H(x)$ has no second derivative at $x=0$.

Comment: OK, sounds interesting - can you explain why?

Comment: When I calculated the second derivative of the inverse of $G(x)$ I got $$\frac{\pi^4((1-x)\log(1-x)+x)x}{36(1-x)\log(1-x)^3}.$$  That's in terms of the original variable $x$. It diverges as $x\to 1$, which corresponds to $H''(y)$ at $y=0$. You need to check this as I'm supposed to be doing something else and I'm not being very careful.

Comment: It might be easier to work with $G(x)=\sum_{i\ge 2} \frac{1}{i(i-1)}x^i=(1-x)\ln(1-x)+x$.  The second derivative of the inverse of $G$ is $$\frac{1}{(1-x)\log(1-x)^3},$$ which diverges at both ends of the interval.

Comment: Thanks Brendan! - some less precise calculations are also getting me to $H''(0)=\infty$ in that case.